# Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException Error calling module function NativeScript

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm trying to upgrade my nativescript app from version 6 to 8 built on angular, i have moved my app-routing.modules accordingly

```
{ path: APP_ROUTES.LOGIN, loadChildren: () => import( "~/app/pages/login/login.module").then((m) => m.LoginModule) },
```

but once the app started it crashes and shows such error.

```
  System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
  System.err: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function
  System.err: TypeError: __webpack_require__.C is not a function
```

this is how my main.ts file look like.

```
// this import should be first in order to load some required settings (like globals and reflect-metadata)
import { platformNativeScript, runNativeScriptAngularApp } from '@nativescript/angular';
import '@angular/compiler';
import 'zone.js'
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";

runNativeScriptAngularApp({
    appModuleBootstrap: () => platformNativeScript().bootstrapModule(AppModule),
  });
```

have a no clue about the issue.